# Spring Roo Jpa Setup fails, maven-eclipse-plugin issue?

Tags: spring, maven, maven-plugin, spring-roo, m2eclipse

I'm using spring roo version 1.2.3. Just a few days ago, the project creation with any package worked fine. But recently, if I create a project with **WAR or POM** packaging, then the **Jpa Setup** command doesn't work.

I give the command

```
project --topLevelPakage com.example.test --packaging POM
Created ROOT/pom.xml
```

Then I type:

```
jpa setup --provider HIBERNATE --database HYPERSONIC_IN_MEMORY
```

it returns

```
additionalBuildCommands element of the maven-eclipse-plugin required
```

I have searched in so many places to find the root of this problem. But without any success. I have checked the **pom.xml** and indeed the additionalBuildCommand element is present there.

```
<plugin>
                    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
                    <version>2.7</version>
                    <!-- Note 2.8 does not work with AspectJ aspect path -->
                    <configuration>
                        <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
                        <downloadJavadocs>false</downloadJavadocs>
                        <wtpversion>2.0</wtpversion>
                        <additionalBuildcommands>
                            <buildCommand>
                                <name>org.eclipse.ajdt.core.ajbuilder</name>
                                <arguments>
                                    <aspectPath>org.springframework.aspects</aspectPath>
                                </arguments>
                            </buildCommand>
                            <buildCommand>
                                <name>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</name>
                            </buildCommand>
                        </additionalBuildcommands>
                        <additionalProjectnatures>
                            <projectnature>org.eclipse.ajdt.ui.ajnature</projectnature>
                            <projectnature>com.springsource.sts.roo.core.nature</projectnature>
                            <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
                        </additionalProjectnatures>
                    </configuration>
                </plugin>
```

Then what is causing the problem? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Packaging pom?

Roo supports 4 Maven packaging types out of the box:

- **jar**. The default, **try with this** (or don't specify packaging at all)
- war. For web projects
- bundle. For OSGI
- pom. For multi-module Maven projects.

The later should contain only a pom and a set of folders, that will be the leaf maven projects (jar, war, and so on)

Comment: Hi jbbarquero, thanks for responding. Yes, jar does solve the jpa setup problem. However, just in case, if I try to create multi module maven projects, this is causing some problem.

Comment: If you create a multi module project, you will create it with some submodules with the appropriate contents (JPA in a JAR submodule, MVC in another submodule, WAR, and so on)

Answer (score 2):

I was facing the same issue. The cause was, that I included the

```
<pluginManger>
```

tag into my pom.xml to solve an maven error that was showing up in eclipse. This hided the plugins section of the pom.xml to spring roo.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Are you sure this is a solution to the problem? Seems misspelled.

Answer (score 0):

Add this default config to POM

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.10</version>
    <configuration>
      <additionalProjectnatures>
        <projectnature>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springnature</projectnature>
      </additionalProjectnatures>
      <additionalBuildcommands>
        <buildcommand>org.springframework.ide.eclipse.core.springbuilder</buildcommand>
      </additionalBuildcommands>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```